# Big Theta as an Equivalence Relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

Forgive me as this is a question inspired by my first computer science algorithms class. I am a math major so when I learned of the big-theta operation on the space of continuous functions I began to wonder what the space of equivalence classes looks like given the big-theta equivalence relation. Is there a countable amount of equivalence classes? I have found any good answers for this question online.

Comment: Consider $x^\alpha$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Yeah thats makes sense to show its not countable. I guess I'm wondering if this space is a little "nicer" than the space of all continuous functions in any notable ways.

Comment: If you keep the CS/algorithms motivation, that seems relevant (time hierarchy theorem) and could be an interesting addition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem